# All visited pages are bundle under a single backslash

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I am newbie with google analytics. Under Reports -> Pages and Screens every page except index.html is bundled under a single backslash. How do view individual pages visited report. I have included a link to screen shot. Thank you

https://imgur.com/a/Ne2GPxN